# How do I name multiple uploaded images and create directories for them in my ASP.NET Core Web Application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

My web application allows users to uploade multiple images for a product.  The problem I have is that, I need to resize the uploaded images into specific widths and I also need to have them named accordingly.  The below action shows you that, any uplaoded image is processed and gives the output location, but it can only process one image.

```
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image700.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image350.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image150.jpg
```

So, what if there is more than one image?  I'm not sure how to handle that.  Ideally I'd like something like:

```
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image01-700.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image01-350.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image01-150.jpg

wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image02-700.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image02-350.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image02-150.jpg

wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image03-700.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image03-350.jpg
wwwroot/images/products/[some id]/image03-150.jpg
```

Here is my controller

```
public Stream ProcessImages(Products model, int? id)
{
    /***************************
    *  These are the image sizes 
    *  I want to make from a single image
    ****************************/
    private readonly int[] sizeArray = new int[] { 700, 350, 150 };

    /***************************
    *  Start Process 
    ****************************/
    try
    {
        /***************************
        *  Define directories
        ****************************/  
        var images = model.ProductImages;
        var root = _env.WebRootPath;
        var folderName = Path.Combine(root, "images", "products", id.ToString());

        /***************************
        *  Create directory (none exists) 
        ****************************/
        if (!Directory.Exists(folderName))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(folderName);
        }

        /***************************
        *  Iterate over the images
        ****************************/
        foreach (var item in images)
        {
            /***************************
            *  Iterate over the required
            *  sizes
            ****************************/
            foreach (var imageSize in sizeArray)
            {
                string imageSizeName = "image" + imageSize + ".jpg";
                string fullPath = Path.Combine(folderName, imageSizeName);
                
                //Create the stream and process the image
                using FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                try
                {
                    Stream inStream = item.OpenReadStream();
                    using Image image = Image.Load(inStream);
                    int width = imageSize;
                    int height = 0;
                    var clone = image.Clone(i => i.Resize(width, height));
                    clone.SaveAsJpeg(fileStream);
                    inStream.Position = 0;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                     Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                 }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
    return (null);
}
```

Here is the model:

```
namespace MyProject.Data
{
    public class Products : BaseEntity
    {        
        public string Title { get; set; }        
        public IFormFileCollection ProductImages { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Does anyone know what I can do to process mulitple images in my situation?

Comment: If that’s the only requirement you’re already almost there. Just keep a counter that you increment each time through the images iteration and add the counter into your path as well.

Comment: For multiple images, have you tried using the list of `IFormFile`, also have you added  enctype="multipart/form-data"  in form tag

Answer (score -1):

for resizing the images you can use the following class

```
    public class ImageResizer
    {
        public void Image_resize(string input_Image_Path, string output_Image_Path, int new_Width)
        {
            const long quality = 50L;
            Bitmap source_Bitmap = new Bitmap(input_Image_Path);
            double dblWidth_origial = source_Bitmap.Width;
            double dblHeigth_origial = source_Bitmap.Height;
            double relation_heigth_width = dblHeigth_origial / dblWidth_origial;
            int new_Height = (int)(new_Width * relation_heigth_width);
            var new_DrawArea = new Bitmap(new_Width, new_Height);
            using (var graphic_of_DrawArea = Graphics.FromImage(new_DrawArea))
            {
                graphic_of_DrawArea.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighSpeed;
                graphic_of_DrawArea.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphic_of_DrawArea.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphic_of_DrawArea.DrawImage(source_Bitmap, 0, 0, new_Width, new_Height);
                using (var output = System.IO.File.Open(output_Image_Path, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    var qualityParamId = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
                    var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
                    encoderParameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(qualityParamId, quality);
                    var codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == ImageFormat.Jpeg.Guid);
                    new_DrawArea.Save(output, codec, encoderParameters);
                    output.Close();
                }
                graphic_of_DrawArea.Dispose();
            }
            source_Bitmap.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

the first argument defines where it can find the picture, the second one asks for a place to save the converted image and the last one asks you for picture width in pixles . ( exactly what you wanted )